# the non-abstract class '_LoginScreenState' is missing implementations for these members

Tags: flutter

i need help to solve the subject error. the class was function well but suddenly its been in error. this is my code in the .dart file to function the login process:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
 import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meal_zone_app/global/global.dart';
import 'package:meal_zone_app/home_screens/seller_home_screen.dart';
import 'package:meal_zone_app/wedgit/custom_text_field.dart';
import 'package:meal_zone_app/wedgit/error_dialog.dart';
import 'package:meal_zone_app/wedgit/loding_dialog.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
   _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
   }

class ***_LoginScreenState*** extends State<LoginScreen> {
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 TextEditingController emailcontroller = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController passwordcontroller = TextEditingController();

formValidation() {
   if (emailcontroller.text.isNotEmpty &&        passwordcontroller.text.isNotEmpty) {
  //login
  logInNow();
} else {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (c) {
        return ErrorDialog(
          message: "Please Enter email/password",
        );
      });
     }
  }

 logInNow() async {
   showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (c) {
      return const LoadingDialog(
        message: "Checking Credentials",
      );
    });
  User? currentuser;
    await firebaseAuth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: emailcontroller.text.trim(),
     password: passwordcontroller.text.trim(),
    )
         .then((auth) {
  currentuser = auth.user!;
   }).catchError((error) {
  Navigator.pop(context);
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (c) {
        return ErrorDialog(
          message: error.message.toString(),
        );
      });
    });
  if (currentuser != null) {
     //login the user
      readDataAndSetDataLocally(currentuser!).then((value) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => const SellerHomeScreen()));
    });
  }
 }

 Future readDataAndSetDataLocally(User currentuser) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("sellers")
      .doc(currentuser.uid)
    .get()
       .then((snapshot) async {
  await sharedPreferences!.setString("uid", currentuser.uid);
   await sharedPreferences!
      .setString("email", snapshot.data()!["selleremail"]);
  await sharedPreferences!
      .setString("name", snapshot.data()!["sellername"]);
  await sharedPreferences!
      .setString("photourl", snapshot.data()!["sellerAvatarUrl"]);
   });
 }
}

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Column(
   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
   children: [
     Container(
       alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
       child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Image.asset(
          "images/seller.png",
          height: 270,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Form(
      key: _formkey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          CustomTextField(
            data: Icons.email,
            controller: emailcontroller,
            hinttext: "Email",
            isOpsecre: false,
          ),
          CustomTextField(
            data: Icons.lock,
            controller: passwordcontroller,
            hinttext: "Password",
            isOpsecre: true,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text(
        "Login",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.green,
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60, vertical: 10)),
      onPressed: () {
        formValidation();
      },
    ),
    const SizedBox(
      height: 30,
      ),
     ],
    ),
  );
}
```

the debug log is :

lib/authintacation/login.dart:18:7: Error: The non-abstract class '_LoginScreenState' is missing implementations for these members:

- State.build
  Try to either
- provide an implementation,
- inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
- mark the class as abstract, or
- provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class _LoginScreenState extends State {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/

Comment: If you format your code (ctrl-alt-L in Android Studio, look it up if something else), the problem will become clear.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing bracket between the `LoginScreen` and `_LoginScreenState`? Please use code formatting, as this will help you to find issues quicker, and it will make it easier for others to assist.

Comment: i checked sir, all closing brackets in its place.